# Setting local Ruby variables from a method or proc's return value

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, local-variables

Say I have a method or a lambda/proc that I want to call, and it's going to be returning a bunch of named values, presumably in a hash, because that's how it's normally done.  Now, some local variables are already defined, but if the method returns new ones, they need to be overridden.  Since it'd be tedious to go through the list of local variables and do a `x ||= h["x"]` for each one, how bad of an idea would it be to just do this?

```
h.each_pair {|k,v| eval("#{k.to_s} = #{v.inspect}") if [String, Symbol].include?(k.class)}
```

I don't think I'd use this for anything more complex than a nested hash, and maybe regexes or ranges at some point, although I might think about properly serializing the output in the future.  But assuming that all of this data is being generated internally, is there anything wrong with doing it this way?  Is there a better way of doing it?

I'd be using it in multiple places, otherwise I wouldn't be going through all this trouble.

Comment: why are you using `eval`? can't you just do `k.to_s = v.inspect`?

Comment: @davidhu2000: There isn't a single class or module in the entire core or standard library which has a `to_s=` method defined. Nor does this have anything even remotely to do with setting local variables.

Comment: It doesn't matter how bad the idea is, since it doesn't work. There is no way to dynamically create local variables. You can only set ones which already exist.

Comment: @jörg: From my original post:
_Now, some local variables are already defined, but if the method returns new ones, they need to be overridden._

So the variables would already be defined, and I would just be changing them.

Comment: The problem is not with the ones that are already defined, the problem is with the ones that aren't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Do you know what the  word "overridden" means?  I'm clearly referring to variables that are already defined, and ONLY variables that are already defined.  No need to respond anymore, you clearly have nothing useful to contribute.

Comment: "Overriden" means "specialized in a subclass", and I don't see how that's relevant here. In your question you say "**some** local variables are already defined", and that part is trivial, it is covered in the Ruby documentation and has been asked and answered a dozen times already. In addition, you also say "if the method returns **new ones**", and that's the part that simply won't work. You cannot create new local variables metaprogrammatically in Ruby. It was possible in Ruby 1.8 and before due to an accidental scope leak in `eval`, but that leak was plugged in Ruby 1.9 and exists no more.